# Как можно получить строку подключения к базе данных Oracle из другого приложения

Tags: c#, oracle11g

Вопрос теоретический, есть база данных, есть приложение которое с ним работает,я сделал второе приложение, назовем его редактор, и эта программа в базе редактирует таблицы, при этом я беру строку подключения в ручном режиме компилирую программу и подключаюсь. Вопрос можно ли как то подключиться к ораклу и узнать строку подключения к серверу, логин и пароль я знаю вопрос именно в строке подключения, ибо на разных компах она будет разная ,все зависит как поставлена программа и база. Как можно решить этот вопрос и можно ли вообще его решить?

Comment: *можно ли как то подключиться к ораклу и узнать строку подключения к серверу* — как подключиться, если вы не знаете строку подключения? Ничего не понял. Делайте конфигурационный файл и храните строку подключения в ней, тогда ее можно будет менять без перекомпиляции программы

Comment: Согласен с вами, вопрос как раз не в этом, имею включенный сервер оракловский я могу как то узнать строку подключения к нему к базе, программно я могу как то узнать эту строку подключения?

Comment: Если бы ее можно было узнать программно, то она была бы не нужна. Она как раз определяет к какому серверу подключаться. И от того как что то установлено на машине где запускается приложение практически не зависит. Она зависит больше от машины на которой установлен сервер БД.